# How to add UICollectionViews to Universal Storyboard and different flowLayout for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout, interface-builder, uicollectionviewlayout

I am developing an **Universal** app. This app should work in `iPhone` and `iPad`. I want to use one `storyboard` for both devices. I need a `UICollectionView` like the pictures.

I am using autolayout in the cell, but I don't know how to solve this. I am using the `any-any` View in the `interfaceBuilder` with `Xcode6`

Any idea? I know I can do it with 2 `storyboards` but I want to learn to use the universal one with `autolayout`.

[image: CollectionView IPAD]

[image: CollectionView iPhone]

Comment: i faced the same problem; did you solve this.. please help